# Using gettimeofday to measure execution time results in weird behaviour

Tags: android, c++, linux, native

I am using gettimeofday to measure the execution time of a function i wrote in c++ native code for an android app. I created a timer class to help me accomplish this:

```
timer::timer(){Reset();}

timer::Reset(){
    timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, 0);
    start_s = t.tv_sec;
    start_ms = t.tv_usec * 0.001f;
}

timer::GetTime(){
    timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, 0);
    return (t.tv_sec - start_s)*1000 + t.tv_usec * 0.001f - start_ms;
}
```

Then, in my main code, I create two timer objects and perform a measurement as follows:

```
main(){
    timer t1, t2;
    stringstream str1;
    t1.Reset();
    for (some count){
        t2.Reset();
        some_function();
        str1 << t2.GetTime() << " ";
    }
    str1 << t1.GetTime();

    output str1;
}
```

But the problem is, when I look at my output results, t1 is almost identical to all the t2 values. An example of the output might be "0.5 0.5 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.55" if the for loop ran five times.

I can't figure out why this might happen.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to say what the problem is from the code you've posted. You should post your actual code or better yet a small, compilable sample program that exhibits your problem. At the very least we need to see the declaration of `timer`.

Comment: Better to use a profiler to get a more accurate measurement.

Comment: The posted code, after fixing obvious compilation errors, exhibits no such problem.

Comment: It is a small portion of a much larger project so I did my best to extract what I thought was necessary to get the point across.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that `start_s` and/or `start_ms` are accidentally declared as static in your timer class and each call inside the loop is updating the shared one from outside the loop.